# StreamReader not throwing FileNotFound exception even though there's no file and it should

Tags: c#

I'm trying to catch possible FileNotFound exceptions but for whatever reason the program ignores the fact the file does not exist and pretends like everything is fine. It returns 0 with the "file" string empty, even though fileName is a string that doesn't match any files in the directory.

```
        string file;


        try
        {
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                file = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return 0;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return -1;
        }
```

It's driving me insane, even though I know with 100% certainty that the answer is going to be extremely obvious.

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't throwing a *different* exception? Or that the file really doesn't exist? If you use a relative path, are you looking in the correct folder? During debugging the current folder is `bin/Debug/...`. Try using `File.Exists` to ensure the file really isn't there and `Path.GetFullPath` to check the absolute path

Comment: BTW this code can be replaced with `File.ReadAllText`. [The source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,827) is identical. The [StreamReader(string)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,fc51cfc8975d71a1) constructor also opens a stream with Read access and share attributes

Comment: Works fine for me. What is the value of `fileName`?

Comment: The file does exist if there's no exception being thrown. Try `Console.WriteLine($"Found file at: {fileStream.Name}");` to see the full path of the file it found.